# Why do I get Network error in Release build in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

This is the first time I'm facing this issue, the app works all fine in the development environment. Checked the console everything works fine but when I made a release apk during the network request the app throws an error `Network Error`.

```
03-11 18:59:26.362  2188  2202 I system_server: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 73297(5652KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 22MB/28MB, paused 2.084ms total 305.053ms
03-11 18:59:26.740  1751 29331 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
03-11 18:59:26.842  1768  1935 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 184320
03-11 18:59:26.875  1768  1935 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 184320
03-11 18:59:26.893 29260 29278 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd641a120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd640f330)
03-11 18:59:26.904  1768  1935 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 184320
03-11 18:59:27.239  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:27.239  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:28.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:28.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:29.056  1758  2036 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 145902833 , only wrote 145685061
03-11 18:59:29.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:29.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:30.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:30.238  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:30.278 29260 29278 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd641a120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd640f330)
03-11 18:59:30.303  2188  3093 W NotificationService: Toast already killed. pkg=com.assignment callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@6847bdb
03-11 18:59:31.110 28097 28107 W webview_servic: Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 149 to 100
03-11 18:59:31.239  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
03-11 18:59:31.239  1767  2527 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

This is the log while running the release apk, I think the error is this `No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)`.

How to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your androidManifest.xml try this :

```
<application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
</application>
```

Bundle it again and rebuild apk , hope it helps feel free for douvts.

Comment: Could you please explain why does this fix this issue? I'm experiencing this issue as well but this change did not solve it...